# PowerShell 5.1 - What is another way to concatenate my array values

Tags: powershell

Given:

- csv integers 100,200
- PowerShell 5.1

I'd like to take the csv integers and make it look like the following:

```
$parmIn = "100,200"
desired output: "(100),(200)"
```

The way it is currently done:

```
   $parmIn = "100,200"
   $x = "(" + "$parmIn".replace(",", "),(") + ")"
```

What's another way to write this more concisely in PowerShell?
I was thinking something with array subexpressions or something.

Answer (score 5):

Use the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```sh
 "100,200" -replace '\d+', '($&)'  # -> "(100),(200)"
```

- Regex `\d+` matches one or more (`+`) decimal digits (`\d`)
- In the replacement expression, `$&` refers to what each `\d+` match captured.